# PDF document in webBrowser control cause 'The memory could not be "read"' error when closing application

Tags: c#, memory, pdf, acrobat

I am using a webBrowser control to open PDF document in winforms, it works fine but when closing the application I get sometimes an error : "The Instruction at "0x2d864aa2" referenced memory at "0x00000008". The memory could not be "read".
Is there a solution for this problem?

Regards.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Believe it or not, yesterday I've been banging my head against this exact same problem and here's the solution I've found. Add the following to the [`FormClosed`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.formclosed.aspx) event:

```
[DllImport("ole32.dll")]
private static extern void CoFreeUnusedLibraries();

private void MainForm_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnFormClosed(e);
    webBrowser1.Visible = false;
    while (webBrowser1.IsBusy)
    {
        Application.DoEvents();
    }
    webBrowser1.Dispose();
    CoFreeUnusedLibraries();
}
```

Actually it seems there's a bug in Adobe Acrobat 9.x causing this exception.

Comment: It works. All I needed was to call the CoFreeUnusedLibraries() with DllImport. As I'm using WPF, I also had to ensure the AllowsTransparency of the window was turned off.